# How to avoid adding SSMA_Timestamp column by SSMA

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, database-migration

SQL Server Migration Assistant add SSMA_Timestamp column to all the tables in the database when migrating from Ms Access to the MSSQL Sever. Is there a way to avoid that?

[image]

Comment: When using Access as front end to SQL server then I recommend you add this "row version" column to each table. When a Access form (or recordset) in Access needs to "check" if the record been changed, it can use the timestamp column. If such a column is missing then Access has to do a field by field comparison.  So I strong recommend that your tables include in this column. You find this reduces errors and update issues from Access as a client (it really is a row version column - not for time). . If you just up-sizing the data and not going to use Access then you don't need the column.

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about SSMA version 7 then try:
Under Tools> Default Project Settings>Tables> Add timestamp columns> Set to Never.

[image]

Comment: May I also ask how to control it from command line?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Set project preference.
     Preference path/name/value can be found in preferences.prefs file stored in SSMA project directory.
     Preference path is the node name path starting from root to leaf node separating by "/". -->
<set-project-preference preference-path="prefs/ssma-for-access/a2ss/conversion"
                            preference-name="timestamp-columns-opt"
                            preference-value="never" />
```